# Can we ban one-liner "Undefined Behavior" answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

Question: [Conflict between a Stanford tutorial and GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559133/conflict-between-a-stanford-tutorial-and-gcc)

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19559192/1633931

Real, much better Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19559236/1633931

1. Doesn't answer the question
2. Shows no effort to understand the situation
3. There is a better answer
4. It's not an answer
5. It gets everyone hive-minded into hounding the question rather than increasing *anyone*'s knowledge of the situation
6. detracts from other answers as if they were inferior.

The only reason this answer was not moderated out was because it was by a high-rep user.

Comment: I don't agree the answer should be _deleted_, but you're right that it's short on usefulness.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The only reason this answer was not moderated out was because it was by a high-rep user.

I disagree. It’s a technically correct answer. It could be better – e.g. by linking a definition of “undefined behaviour” – but I don’t think this is required to make this a legitimate answer.

Furthermore, questions for which this is the correct answer come up *a lot*, and it’s tedious to always provide an in-depth explanation. I’m not saying that instead posting a one-liner is correct, but I’d argue that it’s *understandable*, and I still maintain that in this instance a one-liner is essentially fine.

To answer your points one by one:

> 1 Doesn't answer the question

As I’ve said, it does. Terse, yes. Still an answer.

> 2 Shows no effort to understand the situation

I’d argue differently. Joachim clearly understood the situation well enough to judge that it was UB.

> 3 There is a better answer

… which was posted *later* than Joachim’s, otherwise he probably wouldn’t have bothered (and if he had I’d be on your side).

> 4 It's not an answer

See 1.

> 5 It gets everyone hive-minded into hounding the question rather than increasing anyone's knowledge of the situation

I don’t see that happening here. Do you?

> 6 detracts from other answers as if they were inferior.

That’s a ridiculous accusation.

Comment: Why not close as duplicate then? -I'm sorry that answer just provides no value to anyone. If he doesn't have the time to look up a duplicate/figure out the answer, then **don't answer**

Comment: @imsoconfused what do you propose the question is a duplicate of? Duplicate answer does not mean duplicate question.

Comment: and not backing up your answers is enough to be a legitimate answer? Not as long as I've been on here. I think that's one of the strongest points of SO - the referenced/standards backed reasoning to an answer

Comment: @vcsjones I'm not proposing it's a duplicate, I think it's a great question for people trying to understand how a call stack works. I think the *answer* provides no value and should be removed

Comment: Nobody is going to pull GSQ for something so trivial. The answer is entirely correct- it's undefined behaviour and that's it.

Comment: i mean, look at the second answer I linked to in my post. How can you even argue that the first answer is legitimate in the face of the other detailed, instructive one?

Comment: @DeadMG i know, i expected nothing to happen as a result of this post. I just wanted to bring it to peoples' attention, that's all

Comment: So vote up the better answer.

Comment: @imsoconfused I’m all in favour of closing them. That said, notice that I’ve edited my answer.

Comment: Because the detailed, instructive one covers irrelevant implementation details as an answer to a question about the C language.

Comment: @imsoconfused I’ll add to that: the accepted answer is longer. But it’s **not** better – it’s far worse. I’ve only now read it (I’ve been lulled into false security by its length before!). That “answer” doesn’t actually answer the question at all. It makes no reference to “undefined behaviour” and instead pontificates about irrelevant implementation details in *one particular* implementation. That’s not a good answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph But would you really close that question? Thanks for the edited answer btw, puts my question in perspective.

Comment: @KonradRudolph one particular implementation? What are we all C/C++ gods going to SO for answers? I highly doubt most people will face an environment without a call stack implemented that way for their simple projects, and that's exactly where people learning how to code will learn.

Comment: @imsoconfused To be honest, the question might be specific enough to merit its own answer. But generally, yes, I do think that most “causes UB because of X” questions are similar enough to be considered duplicates for a given X.

Comment: You're all right btw, I just think when answers like that are dismissed for not using the exact term "UB" (he mentions you can't rely on it), it detracts from the learning potential here at SO

Comment: And that's exactly how people learning how to code should not learn!

Comment: @imsoconfused In this particular instance I think that using the exact term is rather important. It’s used in the standard and is a core concept of the language. It also crops up a lot in discussions of the language (exhibit A).

Comment: good point, i'll concede that. @R.MartinhoFernandes Martinho - mmm I *highly* disagree there. Industrial coding is not C++ standard coding. Adherence to standards is the ideal perfection, but I'd argue that knowing implementation details is what makes you a better programmer

Comment: @imsoconfused: I hope, then, that nobody using Visual C++ ever comes across that question. Or ICC. Or Clang.

Comment: @DeadMG does it not? I've learned all my C++ here on SO, so would love to know is VC++ doesn't handle its call stack like that. I was indeed curious that, due to security reasons, the stack was still readable by the next call

Comment: @imsoconfused: They're all different implementations. Not to mention what might happen with GCC of a different version. So unless you want to enumerate every single C++ implementation...

Comment: @vcsjones I know the perfect duplicate for that question. Voted for it just now.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, yep. I'm on board.

Comment: «it’s tedious to always provide an in-depth explanation.» "It's too much trouble to type up a good answer" is no defense whatsoever of a poor answer. Also, if it's true that «questions for which this is the correct answer come up a lot» then a duplicate should be found or manufactured and a high-quality canonical answer attached to it.

Comment: @John That’s why I’ve **explicitly** said that “I’m not saying that instead posting a one-liner is correct”. I’m merely offering it up as an attempted psychological explanation, not a justification.

Answer (score 10):

The answer is entirely correct. It is undefined behaviour, and anything may happen. That's it. As far as the C Standard is concerned, that's all there is to it.

Comment: This answer is ironic.

Comment: hahaha +1 true true, touche. I guess upvoting better answers is all we've got

Comment: -1 This answer is too lengthy to get it's point across.  It should be condensed to more effectively be digested.

Answer (score 10):

> Doesn't answer the question

Why, yes, it does.

> > Q: So the following program, should print 5. Compiling it with gcc results -1218960859. why?
> >
> > A: Because the program's behaviour is undefined.

Could it be better? Yes. Most answers on the site could be improved somehow. Ask the poster to expand if you think it is needed. Or provide a better answer yourself.

> Shows no effort to understand the situation

What effort do you want? "You violated your agreement with the compiler, and the compiler didn't do what you expected" is a perfectly reasonable mental model for this situation. There are other reasonable models, perhaps involving books, hotels, and theft, but that doesn't make this one any less valid or useful.

> There is a better answer

Then upvote the better answer? We aren't in the business of banning answers that are not the best of all.

> It's not an answer

Why, yes, it is. See above. Why am I replying to the same point twice?

> It gets everyone hive-minded into hounding the question rather than increasing anyone's knowledge of the situation

I really hope you are not trying to insinuate that answer has super secret mind-control powers. If SO denizens get "hive-minded" into doing whatever due to some answer that, according to you, is so obviously bad, I think we have a bigger problem to solve here.

> detracts from other answers as if they were inferior

It doesn't mention other answers at all, so I fail to see how it makes them look inferior. That is, unless it itself looks superior. Why would someone think it looks superior, though?

Comment: +1 for secret mind control powers.